# Why is this rspec post request use 'as: :js'?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I see a line in an rspec 3.4 test, Rails 4.2 app such as:

```
response = post some_action_path, email: 'example@mailinator.com', as: :js
```

In the corresponding controller action, I see the following respond to block:

```
class SomeActionController < Application Controller
  respond_to :js
  def create
     # some code that we go through to process some_action_path post request
    respond_to do |format|
      unless @some_result["some_error"].present?
        format.json { render json: @result, status: :ok }
         format.html
      else
         format.json { render json: @result, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html
      end
    end
  end
```

Shouldn't the line be `format: js` or `format: json`?  If not, what is the point of `as: :js`?  I ask because specifying `as: :js` seems to cause the test to hang....

Comment: The `respond_to :js` does the same thing. Is there a create.js file in your views directory?'

Comment: No, there's only a create.html.erb

Comment: `:js` is a valid response type for Rails. It's used for dynamic JavaScript responses. Not sure if it was meant to be `:json` in the test suite.